# Maven build(with Flexmojos) for multi module project throwing an error

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flexmojos

I am trying to setup a Flex/Java multi module project in Eclipse. Using Maven to run the build and generate the war file. The details of the versions I am using are as follows:

```
   Flexmojos : 3.5.0  
   Flex framework/compiler : 4.5.1.21328  
   Target player : 10.2.0
```

And the playerglobal dependency in my pom file uses classifier as 10.2 with version 4.5.1.21328

Now when I run the build using 'mvn install', I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:3.5.0:compile-swf
>   (default-compile-swf) on project client: **TargetPlayer and
>   playerglobal dependency version doesn't match! Target player: 10.2.0,
>   player global: 10.2** -> [Help 1]

Any ideas why this might be happening?
I tried just playing around changing those version numbers, but still couldn't make it work for Flex 4.5.1. Please let me know how to go about this (and if you need more information). Thanks.

Regards
Basith

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply referencing "10.2" instead of "10.2.0"? I think there was only one Flash player deployed with a 3-segment version number.